# Stuck in moving graph using achartEngine

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

Hi friends i have used graphs in my android application. In that i update graph in every second .Now i want to move this graph from right to left as it update the value.Any one have any idea how to do so? Any help appreciated.

```
 dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

         renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

         renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(12);
         renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
         renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01));
         renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
         renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
         renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
         renderer.setPointSize(5f);
         renderer.setShowGrid(true);
         renderer.setXTitle("Time");
         renderer.setYTitle("Number");

         rendererSeries = new XYSeriesRenderer();

         rendererSeries.setColor(Color.BLUE);
         rendererSeries.setFillBelowLine(false);
         rendererSeries.setFillPoints(true);
         rendererSeries.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
         renderer.addSeriesRenderer(rendererSeries);

         timeSeries = new TimeSeries("Random");
         mThread = new Thread(){
             public void run(){
                 while(true){
                     try {
                         Thread.sleep(2000L);
                     } 
                     catch (InterruptedException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }

                     timeSeries.add(new Date(), random.nextInt(10));
                     mchartView.repaint();
                 }
             }
         };
         mThread.start();

         dataset.addSeries(timeSeries);
         mchartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(Pedometer.this, dataset, renderer);
         mchartView.refreshDrawableState();
         mchartView.repaint();

         llChart.addView(mchartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Comment: Posting your code for your activity including the graph update sections would make it much easier to answer.

Comment: @KushalShah: Buddy mail me ur stuff, i am also currently  working on Graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use setRange to set the required range each time you add a new point. For example:

```
double maxX = timeSeries.getMaxX();
double minX = maxX - deltaX; // deltaX is your required x-range
double maxY = timeSeries.getMinY();
double minY = timeSeries.getMaxY();

renderer.setRange(new double[] { minX, maxX, minY, maxY });
```

This way your right edge always show the maximum time and the rest of the graph will move from right to left.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey bro does setRange property is of achartEngine library???? I don't find any...

Comment: You are right. Sorry for that, I've corrected my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your graph to move, you need to add new data as you are doing.  Once the graph is *full* (has as many points as you want) you need to start removing the oldest points.  This will give you a window that will display the newest X number of points.

If you are using the TimeSeries I think your using you should be able to call `timeSeries.setMaximumItemCount(maxNumPoints)` and the time series will take care of the rest.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi thnx for the response but timeSeries haven't show me this kind of property.

Comment: Does it have a delete method?  What ia the import statement for the timeseries (what package are you using)  I found several implimentations online and they all had a maxcount property and a delete method.

Comment: I can't be sure but it looks like you are using `aChartEngine`.  The timeseries in this package includes a `remove(index)` method.  If you know the index of the oldest item you could remove it that way.  Or, try the `aFreeChart` package.  It has the `setMaximumItemCount(maxNumPoints)` method which will make it all happen automatically.  (I have no affiliation with any of these projects)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to let your graph auto-calculate its axes min and max is to set them to a min and max value, and then repaint. For example:

```
mRenderer.setXAxisMax(-Double.MAX_VALUE);
mRenderer.setXAxisMin(Double.MAX_VALUE);
mRenderer.setYAxisMax(-Double.MAX_VALUE);
mRenderer.setYAxisMin(Double.MAX_VALUE);

mChartView.repaint();
```

I don't know if it's the *best* option, but it works for me !

**reference :** [My Android AChartEngine is already working, but how to make it look good?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309065/my-android-achartengine-is-already-working-but-how-to-make-it-look-good)

Answer (score 0):

In my code I came up with the following idea:

```
    private void animatePlot(float t, float[] v) {
            // moving plot
            datasets[i].add(t, v[i]);
            if (mPointsCount > GRAPH_RESOLUTION)
                datasets[i].remove(0);
            view.repaint();
            mPointsCount++;
    }
```

- t and v correspond the x,y plot values.
- t is growing.
- when I get new data (t and v) I call this function.
- GRAPH_RESOLUTION is the amount of points shown in the graph from
  which the plot starts moving to the left.